# Quick way to modify a tuple value from list to string?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have an API that returns values in the following form:

```
[('ABC123', ['DEF456']), ('EFG789', ['HIJ123'])]
```

Using python, I am attempting to return a list of tuples with only string values.  For any tuple value that is a list, I only seek to return the sole value of that list.

Proposed output:

```
[('ABC123', 'DEF456'), ('EFG789', 'HIJ123')]
```

I've attempted to use a list comprehension, but I haven't been too successful with my attempt.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a comprehension

```
result = [(a, b[0]) for a, b in original_list]
```

Comment: Simple and effective.  Had no idea I can do a two-variable list comprehension.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis: in a comprehension, you can do anything you could do in a for-loop

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the index of the list within the tuple:

```
In [1]: aa = [('ABC123', ['DEF456']), ('EFG789', ['HIJ123'])]
In [2]: out = [tuple(j if not isinstance(j, list) else j[0] for j in i) for i
   ...: in aa]

In [3]: out
Out[3]: [('ABC123', 'DEF456'), ('EFG789', 'HIJ123')]
```

Answer (score 1):

A version using only iterators:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

parse = lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, list) else x[0]
Y = zip(map(itemgetter(0), X), map(parse, map(itemgetter(1), X)))

print(list(Y))
```

The output is:

```sh
[('ABC123', 'DEF456'), ('EFG789', 'HIJ123')]
```